# Can we restrict Tablet support from a specific update

Tags: android

I already have an Android Application in the play store which is supporting both phones and Tablet Devices.

Now **how can I give an update to it so that the new update should only support phones but not Tablet Devices?**

I know we can restrict it from the manifest. But does play store support my new update as there are already users with tablet devices?

TIA

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Even if you have ideas for a better tablet version in the future, why take away people's ability to use it until then?  You gain nothing and piss off users.  Its not like there's even a good definition of what a "tablet" is vs a "phone".  Is a 6 inch device a tablet?  7?  7.5?  Its all entirely arbitrary.